# Morphia 2.0.0-RC1 query returns empty list just after I have saved an object

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am trying to get Morphia to work with mongoDB and am able to save my object into the database. But when I try to retrieve all objects i get an empty list?

I am using mongo db java driver 3.12.0 and morphia 2.0.0-rc1. The old execute method has been deprecated since 2.0 but the reference guide has not been updated. I looked through the code on github and calling iterator directly instead of using execute before seems to be the right way now.

Update: by just adding any filter i get results?

```
public class MongoDBConnectorTest {
@Test
public void test() {
    //MongoDatabase db = MongoDBConnector.getClient().getDatabase("lottoDB");
    //MongoCollection<Lotto> lottoCollection = db.getCollection("lotto", Lotto.class);

    Datastore lottoDatastore = LottoDataStore.getLottoDataStore().getDataStore();

    //System.out.println(db.getName());

    final Lotto lotto = new Lotto();
    lotto.setHighestPriceMoney(100000);

    // Insert lotto object
    //lottoCollection.insertOne(lotto);
    lottoDatastore.save(lotto);

    // Find it again
    //final Query<Lotto> query = lottoDatastore.find(Lotto.class);
    //List<Lotto> lottos = (List<Lotto>) query.iterator().toList();
    final Query<Lotto> query = lottoDatastore.find(Lotto.class);
    final List<Lotto> lottos = query.iterator().toList();
    final Lotto lotto2 = query.first();
    //Lotto lotto2 = query.first();

    System.out.println("Lotto found:");
    System.out.println(lottos.size());
    System.out.println(lotto2);

}
}
```

LottoDataStore.java

```
public class LottoDataStore {
private static LottoDataStore lottoDataStore = null;
protected final Datastore datastore;

public static LottoDataStore getLottoDataStore() {
    if(lottoDataStore == null) lottoDataStore = new LottoDataStore();

    return lottoDataStore;
}

private LottoDataStore() {
    this.datastore = Morphia.createDatastore(MongoDBConnector.getClient().getMongoClient(), "lottoDB");
    // tell Morphia where to find your classes
    // can be called multiple times with different packages or classes
    datastore.getMapper().mapPackage("com.j.productdata.model.entity.lotto");
    datastore.ensureIndexes();
}

public Datastore getDataStore() {
    return datastore;
}
```

}

Lotto.java

```
@Entity("lotto")
public class Lotto {
@Id
protected String alias = "lotto";

@BsonProperty(value = "highest_price_money")
protected int highestPriceMoney;

@BsonProperty(value = "average_price_money")
protected int averagePriceMoney;

@BsonProperty(value = "min_cost")
protected int minCost;

@BsonProperty(value = "min_cost_highest_price_money")
protected int minCostHighestPriceMoney;

List<LottoResult> results;

public Lotto() {

}

public String getAlias() {
    return alias;
}



public void setAlias(String alias) {
    this.alias = alias;
}



public int getHighestPriceMoney() {
    return highestPriceMoney;
}



public void setHighestPriceMoney(int highestPriceMoney) {
    this.highestPriceMoney = highestPriceMoney;
}



public int getAveragePriceMoney() {
    return averagePriceMoney;
}



public void setAveragePriceMoney(int averagePriceMoney) {
    this.averagePriceMoney = averagePriceMoney;
}



public int getMinCost() {
    return minCost;
}



public void setMinCost(int minCost) {
    this.minCost = minCost;
}



public int getMinCostHighestPriceMoney() {
    return minCostHighestPriceMoney;
}



public void setMinCostHighestPriceMoney(int minCostHighestPriceMoney) {
    this.minCostHighestPriceMoney = minCostHighestPriceMoney;
}



public List<LottoResult> getResults() {
    return results;
}



public void setResults(List<LottoResult> results) {
    this.results = results;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Lotto [id=" + alias + ", highestPriceMoney=" + highestPriceMoney + ", minCost=" + minCost
            + ", minCostHighestPriceMoney=" + minCostHighestPriceMoney + ", results=" + results + "]";
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me using the [reproducer](https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/reproducer) and 2.0.0-RC1.  I'm not entirely sure what's going on locally that you're not seeing the results.  There are some oddities in the code, though.  You have a number of driver annotations in your code.  That's fine as far as it goes but Morphia doesn't use those annotations.

It might be that package you're mapping doesn't match where `Lotto` lives but i would expected an error about a missing `Codec` in that case.

Comment: First, thank you for your work with Morphia, much appreciated! 

Do you have any suggestions regarding a Codec? If I add a filter to the query i.e.
   final Query<Lotto> query = lottoDatastore.find(Lotto.class);
   query.filter(Filters.exists("alias"));
   final List<Lotto> lottos = query.iterator().toList();

It works.

Comment: I found the issue - when I registered the MongoClient I had added the PojoCoded. Without this codec it works. Awesome, thank you!

Comment: Morphia will configure the mongo client with the correct codec provider to find the codecs it builds for your entities.  If you had manually added `PojoCodec`, the then registry was likely finding that instead and you were saving your entity in another collection. I'm guessing if you look in the `Lotto` collection rather than `lotto` where morphia is looking you'll find the missing documents.